# How can i parse a link from a line in a html source?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string downloaddifrectory;
    string mainurl = "http://www.usgodae.org/ftp/outgoing/fnmoc/models/navgem_0.5/latest_data/";
    List<string> parsedlinks = new List<string>();
    string path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Parseanddownloadfiles();
    }

    private void Parseanddownloadfiles()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(mainurl, path_exe + "\\page.html");
        }

        string firsttag = "href";
        string lasttag = ">";
        int index = 0;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path_exe + "\\page.html");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains("href"))
            {
                int first = lines[i].IndexOf(firsttag, index);
                string result = lines[i].Substring(first + 2,);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm trying to use in this case with indeox and substring.
This is the link for the source view of the html page:

[Source View](http://view-source:http://www.usgodae.org/ftp/outgoing/fnmoc/models/navgem_0.5/latest_data/)

And for example in the source view one of the lines in the source view is:

```
<img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="US058GCOM-GR1mdl.0018_0056_00000F0RL2015110900_0001_000000-000000grnd_sea_temp">US058GCOM-GR1mdl.0018_0056_00000F0RL2015110900_0001_000000-000000grnd_sea_temp</a>       09-Nov-2015 04:23  444K
```

And if i make right click on the part:

US058GCOM-GR1mdl.0018_0056_00000F0RL2015110900_0001_000000-000000grnd_sea_temp

I can copy the link address i get:

http://www.usgodae.org/ftp/outgoing/fnmoc/models/navgem_0.5/latest_data/US058GCOM-GR1mdl.0018_0056_00000F0RL2015110900_0001_000000-000000grnd_sea_temp

And if i will paste now this ftp link to my browser it will download the file.

What i need to do my main goal is to download all this files in each line that have this kind of links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse an html page, use an html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Here is a working code

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.usgodae.org/ftp/outgoing/fnmoc/models/navgem_0.5/latest_data/");

var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
            .Select(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value)
            .ToList();
```

Now you can use HttpClient, HttpWebRequest or WebClient to download the file.